# How to change text in a <p> tag when hovering a button in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to change the text of a `<p>` to *David* and *Larry* accordingly when each button (that has an image inside) has hovered. I have experimented with numerous things and found a way to change the CSS of **the button** with a function. But I was unable to find anything to change text since `<p>` is in a different class. Any suggestions to address this problem?

*For your information, I have added a CSS color changing function I used earlier to the below code sample.*

here's my code.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import "./Tri.css";

function Tri() {
    function davidon(e) {
        e.target.style.background = 'red';
    }

    function davidoff(e) {
        e.target.style.background = 'green';
    }
    function larryon(e) {
        e.target.style.background = 'red';
    }

    function larryoff(e) {
        e.target.style.background = 'green';
    }

    return (  
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>

                <button onMouseOver={davidon} onMouseLeave={davidoff}>
                    <img src={require(`./images/david.png`)} className="david"/>
                </button>

                <button onMouseOver={larryon} onMouseLeave={larryoff}>
                    <img src={require(`./images/larry.png`)} className="larry"/>
                </button>
                </div>

                <div className="plex">
                    <p>Larry Or David?</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    );

}

export default Tri;
```

Thanks in advance for you replies.

Comment: have you tried using `useState` and changing the state `onMouseOver`? Also, don't manipulate the dom manually i.e directly updating `e.target.style.background`.

Comment: you should refer to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to learn more about state.

Answer (score 3):

You need to think more in "React", and use component state and props. The [offical documentation](https://reactjs.org/) is a good place to start.

Here I've got two components.

1) `Tri`: which has it's own state, and builds the HTML using Button components

2) `Button`: since you need each button to change color depending on the mouse action it's best to separate that functionality out into a new component so that each instance can have its own state.

(I've intentionally left out the images in this example, but you could pass in a `src` prop to the button and have that handle the images too if you wanted.)

```js
const { useState } = React;

// `Button` accepts a props object
// Here I've destructured out the button name,
// and the handleHover function
function Button({ name, handleHover }) {

  // We initialise the state with "green"
  const [ color, setColor ] = useState('green');

  function handleColor() {

    // We set the new color based on the current color
    setColor(color => color === 'red' ? 'green' : 'red');

    // And then call the `handleHover` function, passing in `name`
    handleHover(name);
  }

  return (
    <button
      className={color}
      onMouseOver={handleColor}
      onMouseLeave={handleColor}
    >
      {name}
    </button>
  );
}

function Tri() {
  
  // In `Tri` we set its own state for the name
  // initialised to an empty string
  const [ name, setName ] = useState('');
  
  // A handler that changes the name
  // This is the function we pass to each button
  function handleHover(name) {
    setName(name);
  }
  
  // Set up two buttons using our Button component
  // assigning a name to each, and passing in our handler
  // Whenever the name (state) is changed the name in the
  // paragraph also changes
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Button name="Larry" handleHover={handleHover} />
        <Button name="David" handleHover={handleHover} />
      </div>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tri />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
.green { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using states. And don't change DOM-nodes dynamically in event handlers. Always use React functionality:

React uses a declarative form of programming (The Virtual DOM specifically). You define variables and set them and React updates the DOM if those change.

`useState` gives you the opportunity to declare an editable (through a setter function) variable. See Docs on [State and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Tri.css";

function Tri(props) {
    // props as immutable arguments (if needed)


    // useState keeps an internal state in the component
    let initialTxt = 'Larry Or David?';
    const [text, setText] = React.useState(initialTxt);


    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button
                        className="david-btn"
                        onMouseOver={() => setText('David')}
                        onMouseLeave={() => setText(initialTxt)}>
                        <img src={require(`./images/david.png`)} className="david"/>
                    </button>

                    <button
                        className="larry-btn"
                        onMouseOver={() => setText('Larry')}
                        onMouseLeave={() => setText(initialTxt)}>>
                        <img src={require(`./images/larry.png`)} className="larry"/>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div className="plex">
                    <p>{text}</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    );

}
```

Also, extend `./Tri.css` with the following code. You could use a style-variable but that would make your code more bloated and unreadable if you have access to CSS.

```
.david-btn,
.larry-btn {
    background-color: green;
}

.david-btn:hover,
.larry-btn:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Refs`. You can read more about them in [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).
I've created a [simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-meadow-ztgji) (based on your code).

Step by step what I did:

1. import `useRef` hook which is used to create reference.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
```

2. created reference:

```js
const pTagRef = useRef();
```

3. passed reference to your `p` tag

```
<div ref={pTagRef} className="plex">
    <p>Larry Or David?</p>
</div>
```

4. created function which can change the content of this reference where `pTagRef.current` is DOM element.

```js
function setName(name) {
    if (pTagRef.current) {
      pTagRef.current.innerText = name;
    }
}
```

5. called the function whenever name changed

```js
setName("larry");
```

---

You should definitely use [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for this but I hope this one helps you to get started.